# Do docker overlay networks support communication from hosts to container?

Tags: linux, docker, networking

I have a mixed network of bare metal hosts running services and docker hosts providing applications that connect to the host services. (In my case Jupyter notebooks in containers running pyspark that connect to a spark master host to distribute the work.) Therefore I have a requirement for the host network to be able to resolve the address of the container and also route traffic back.For my example, the container is making an RMI call into the service host but the host can not route back (and fails).

If I setup my services to be from container to container using an overlay network everything works, but I am unable to use the basic management consoles from my host network as they can not route back to container.

Below is how I setup my overlay network and and tested between two hosts.

Do docker overlay networks support communication from hosts to container?

---

**Setup**

```
 bgercken@docker-manager ~]$  docker network create --driver=overlay --attachable --subnet=192.168.0.208/28 --gateway=192.168.0.209 container-net

[bgercken@docker-manager ~]$ docker container run -d --rm --name container1 -h container1 --net container-net --ip 192.168.0.210 alpine ping 8.8.8.8

[bgercken@titan ~]$ docker container run -d --rm --name container2 -h container2 --net container-net --ip 192.168.0.211 alpine ping 8.8.8.8
31853b87848f7c70e806f6f9c9d7b457fce6d64c0efa832b0e6991034132f453

[bgercken@titan ~]$ docker container exec -it container2 sh
/ # ping -c 1 container1
PING container1 (192.168.0.210): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.210: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.656 ms

[bgercken@docker-manager ~]$ docker container exec -it container1 sh
/ # ping -c 1 container2
PING container2 (192.168.0.211): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.211: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.557 ms

--- container2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.557/0.557/0.557 ms

/ # ping -c 1 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: seq=0 ttl=63 time=0.492 ms

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.492/0.492/0.492 ms


[root@docker-manager bgercken]# route add -net 192.168.0.208 netmask 255.255.255.240 gw 192.168.0.209


iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT

iptables -A DOCKER -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DOCKER -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT


[root@docker-manager bgercken]# ping -c 1 container1
PING container1.ktdev.net (192.168.0.210) 56(84) bytes of data.
From docker-manager.ktdev.net (192.168.0.191) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

--- container1.ktdev.net ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, +1 errors, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

[root@docker-manager bgercken]# netstat -nr
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens192
10.0.156.64     192.168.0.160   255.255.255.192 UG        0 0          0 tunl0
10.0.173.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U         0 0          0 *
10.0.173.11     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 calicc9e1866c3e
10.0.173.12     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 calibb3849d04c0
10.0.198.64     192.168.0.200   255.255.255.192 UG        0 0          0 tunl0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker_gwbridge
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens192
192.168.0.208   192.168.0.209   255.255.255.240 UG        0 0          0 ens192
```

**Docker Info**

```
Containers: 52
 Running: 37
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 15
Images: 37
Server Version: 17.06.2-ee-16
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-thinpool
 Pool Blocksize: 524.3kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74GB
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Data file:
 Metadata file:
 Data Space Used: 6.259GB
 Data Space Total: 153GB
 Data Space Available: 146.7GB
 Metadata Space Used: 2.085MB
 Metadata Space Total: 1.606GB
 Metadata Space Available: 1.604GB
 Thin Pool Minimum Free Space: 15.3GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: true
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: true
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Library Version: 1.02.146-RHEL7 (2018-01-22)
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: active
 NodeID: nzx7kf0t3z42yuxmqsw3e96s8
 Is Manager: true
 ClusterID: m5851n1g1jt62my16of5bbrgw
 Managers: 1
 Nodes: 3
 Orchestration:
  Task History Retention Limit: 5
 Raft:
  Snapshot Interval: 10000
  Number of Old Snapshots to Retain: 0
  Heartbeat Tick: 1
  Election Tick: 10
 Dispatcher:
  Heartbeat Period: 5 seconds
 CA Configuration:
  Expiry Duration: 3 months
  Force Rotate: 0
  External CAs:
    cfssl: https://192.168.0.191:12381/api/v1/cfssl/sign
 Root Rotation In Progress: false
 Node Address: 192.168.0.191
 Manager Addresses:
  192.168.0.191:2377
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 6e23458c129b551d5c9871e5174f6b1b7f6d1170
runc version: 462c82662200a17ee39e74692f536067a3576a50
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-862.9.1.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 15.51GiB
Name: docker-manager.ktdev.net
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: Docker bridge to the rescue

Found a solution to my particular problem. In this configuration the calls originating in the container reach out to the host network and the calls complete correctly.

Agreed that this is not a best practice, but will bridge the gap until all the worker nodes are moved into containers.

Cheers.

**Details**

Designate a subnet for the pool of addresses that will be used for launching containers on the master node.

All the container names for the subnet are in DNS:

```
#
# 192.168.0.208/28
#
192.168.0.208   dbr0-ep1
192.168.0.209   dbr0-gw
192.168.0.210   container1
...
192.168.0.222   container12
192.168.0.223 dbr0-ep2
```

Create the docker bridge on the master host (titan 192.168.0.160):

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.0.208/28 --gateway=192.168.0.209 dbr0
```

Add a route on each worker node host that routes back to the subnet designated for running the containers (x.x.x160 is the master):

```
route add -net 192.168.0.208 netmask 255.255.255.240 gw 192.168.0.160
```

Start the container on the master (titan):

```
[bgercken@titan ~]$ docker container run -d --rm --name container1 -h container1 \
  --net=dbr0 --ip=192.168.0.210 debian sleep infinity
...
[bgercken@titan ~]$ ping -c 1 192.168.0.210
PING 192.168.0.210 (192.168.0.210) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.210: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms

--- 192.168.0.210 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.027/0.027/0.027/0.000 ms
```

On the worker nodes:

```
[bgercken@node1 ~]$ ping -c 1 container1
PING container1.ktdev.net (192.168.0.210) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from container1.ktdev.net (192.168.0.210): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.256 ms

--- container1.ktdev.net ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.256/0.256/0.256/0.000 ms

[bgercken@node2 ~]$ ping -c 1 container1
PING container1.ktdev.net (192.168.0.210) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from container1.ktdev.net (192.168.0.210): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.370 ms

--- container1.ktdev.net ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.370/0.370/0.370/0.000 ms
```